# Package parsing error installing APK

Tags: android, android-studio, parsing, package, apk

Hello I have small issue with my APK. I have been developing and testing an application for past couple weeks without any issue with the APK file. Every time I was able to build app-debug.apk and install it to my smartphone.

Today I decided to publish my app and followed the whole process. The only thing I done in Android studio was: "Generate Signed APK..." where I created new key and build the signed APK in order to publish my application. (I also included some .png resources for the icon but I am not using it right now so I do not think that could be the issue.)

Right now the app is still pending to be published and I wanted to try the app once more on my phone so I build the app-debug.apk as usual but this time I get error: "There is a problem parsing the package" while installing the application.

I have searched the forum and tried some answers, e.g. uninstalling any previous version, for this issue but nothing seemed to work.

Thank you for any advice.

EDIT:
I was able to install the app while connected to PC directly, and received error that the is referencing the APP being not uninstalled properly. So I uninstalled the APP properly and now I am able to RUN the app or DEBUG the app but if I create APK (Signed/Unsigned or debug version), download it and install on the phone, the issue keeps going.

Answer (score 0):

Install the application while it's connected to your pc with logcat running. You'll see a proper error message.

Comment: I was able to install the app while connected to PC directly, and received error that the is referencing the APP being not uninstalled properly. So I uninstalled the APP properly and now I am able to RUN the app or DEBUG the app but if I create APK (SIgned/Unsigned or debug version), download it and install on the phone, the issue keeps going.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons for this error ...i faced this error on when:-
1.The app was not uninstalled properly from android device.
to solve this go to settings>Apps and notification> App info > unistall app for all users.
2.Parsing error is sometimes shown due to unsigned apk.(vary depending on versions of android)
Try building a signed apk and use that //google how to build a signed apjk in android studio.
3.My antivirus was deleting .dex files that lead to improper packaging of apk.
Try solving that...in your antivirus settings
4.Try Android studio> file >invalidate catche and restart..and it may solve your problem(works sometime..)

Comment: Thank you for advice! But uninstall the app properly does not help, Signed APK neither (tried all versions of APK none works), and Invalidating catche did not help as well. I will try the antivirus option as soon as I get home.
Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

try installing from different file explorer. instead of cyanogen File explorer use esexplorer or someother. it worked for me